# Email forwarding

Tags: email, postfix, forwarding, wildcard

We run multiple brands on multiple servers, and what we basically want is for Postfix (which I have set up and forwarding successfully) to forward on `<username>@brand2.com` to `<username>@brand1.com`.

All it needs to do is receive mail for any username at brand 2 and forward it to the same username but at brand 1.

So for example if I emailed `dave@brand2.com` it would forward it to `dave@brand1.com` .

Is this possible, if so could anyone advise how I would go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a trivial thing. Postfix has two mechanisms similar to forwarding: first, the "orderly" /etc/aliases, and the second is the virtual aliasing. Its configuration file is in most cases in `/etc/postfix/virtual`. This second is capable to the so-named "domain forwarding", by the most trivial syntax:

```
@brand1.com: @brand2.com
```

Don't forget to run a `postmap virtual` after changing this file.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Would I be correct in assuming then that this would work for all users automatically? As in I wouldn't need to add a line for each user.

Comment: @DavidThompson Yes, it forwarded every user automatically. You can even combine this with non-domain aliases (for example, forward every mail from brand1.com to bigbrother_at_brand3.com AND brand2.com). If you are satisfied with an answer, don't forget to accept it (by clicking the pipe on the left side). It is a big reward to the answering person.